# C# data structure for finding current item based on ranges

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I am looking for a data structure or confirmation one doesn't exist where you can input items and a numerical value associated with eh beginning of that item being valid.

Imagine that you're trying to find out your reward for a high score.

The elements would look something like this:
0 - nothing 
100 - silver star
300 - gold star

I'd then like to quickly evaluate my current reward or any generic item based on my current score. If I pass in 270, I get silver star.

When I first had to implement something like this, I used a list of duples, the first value being the numeric floor and the second being the item. Of course this works. But of course as the list grows, so does the lookup time.

I have to implement something similar to this again but with normalized values. Again, I can do the same thing, but if there is a better more efficient way using a tree, please point me in that direction.

Regardless of the correct structure, I'll write a wrapper for the normalized and raw value search.

Comment: How many stars are we talking about, 5, 50000, 10000000. are you adding them dynamically, or often, are they changing much or is it static. if this is for a couple of items you already have your answer

Comment: Have you tried binary search?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var levels = new []
{
    new { score = 0, level = "nothing" },
    new { score = 100, level = "silver" },
    new { score = 300, level = "gold" },
};

var score = 270;

var level = levels.OrderBy(x => x.score).Where(x => x.score <= score).Last().level;

Console.WriteLine(level);
```

That gives me `silver` on the console.

Comment: I was thinking about an answer like this, but i really wanted to add pictures :P upvote

Comment: This would produce a correct answer but my question wasn't about using LINQ to solve this, it was about efficiency of the data structure. Still, your answer is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @user923 - Could you not apply a binary search to the list?